# Extract domain with protocol and country code from the link in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is the standard formula to extract the domain root with protocols:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[^/]+"))
```

Can anyone help me edit it so that I will be able to extract the domain root with protocols and the country code after slash?
For example,

```
https://www.example.com/uk/exampling/example
https://www.example.com/nz/examping/example
```

I need to get:

```
https://www.example.com/uk/
https://www.example.com/nz/
```

Comment: So you want `^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?[^/]+/[^/]+/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?[^/]+/[^/]+/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zEV6rr/2)

Details:

- `^` - start of  string
- `(?:https?://)?` - an optional occurrence of `http://` or `https://`
- `(?:www\.)?` - an optional occurrence of `www`.
- `[^/]+/[^/]+/` - two occurrences of 1+ chars other than `/` and then a `/` (can be written as `(?:[^/]+/){2}`)